# Where to put code to highlight drop destination in Swift OSX?

Tags: swift, macos, drag-and-drop

I know how to draw a border for a view in the method "override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect)"

But, where would I put the code to draw the border only when a file is being dragged into the drag destination view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, maybe I haven't worded the question very well, as there's been no replies! Or, maybe it's such a dumb question...

In the drawRect method you need to put the drawing code in an if block

```
if (highlight)
  { 
    // draw red outline
    } else { 
    // draw grey outline
  }
```

Then, in draggingEntered method:

```
    highlight = true
    self.setNeedsDisplayInRect(self.bounds)
```

In draggingExited method:

```
    highlight = false
    self.setNeedsDisplayInRect(self.bounds)
```